# Interpret coefficient of negative binomial regression

Tags: regression, spss, regression-coefficients

Am I understanding this right? I have run a negative binomial regression on overdispersed count data (Y is number of litter items found, and X is the distance to the shoreline), in SPSS. The omnibus test result is highly significant but I'm quite puzzled when interpreting the coefficient in the parameter estimate:
[image]

If I understand correctly, for every increase in X (i.e. the independent variable), I will have a decrease in log count in the Y (i.e dependent variable). The result of this is significant so I can trust it. When I look at the coefficient B (-,042) I understand it being in natural logarithm form, so I could interpret it as a decrease of 3,17 quantity of litter? (that is changing -,042 in natural log form to a standard numeric form).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure how you are getting the 3.17. Taking the exponent of -0.042 returns 0.959. Thus, for every one-unit increase in distance, the number of litters decreases by 4% [(1 - 0.959)x100=4].

Comment: thanks for your input. Well, I must have made an error somewhere then, my bad!

Comment: so here just which exponent did you consider?

Comment: The log link used in negative-binomial regression is the natural log, which has base = e. Thus, the antilog is e^x. In most software programs (and calculators), this is exp().